# padding and colour not applying to body class

Tags: html, sass, colors, padding

I have been trying to apply padding and colour to my body element and it is not applying.

I have been on this and it is not working. I am using live server for my work though, I will apply my code below for review. both the css and the html. it should also be noted that I am using SASS. Thanks

```css
body {
    font-family: 'lato', sans-serif;
   font-weight: 400;
   //font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 1.7;
   color: $color-grey-dark;
    padding: 3rem; 
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icon-font.css"> 
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> 
            <title>A7A ASSOCIATES LTD</title>
        </head> 
        <body>
            <header class="header">
                <div class="header__logo-box">
                 <img src="img/A7A  Logo.png" alt="logo" class="header__logo">
                </div>
                <nav></nav>
            </header>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you place those CSS rules after the HTML closing tag ?

anyway, here are few solutions:

- put the CSS style inside `css/style.css` file and it shall work.
- make sure the path to the CSS file is correct.
- clear the browser cache and try again (CTRL+F5 for Firefox, Shift+F5 for chrome)

Comment: my css is working fine, it is in a different file, i just wrote it down that way so it will be easier to see the code. i cleared my cache and did everything and the padding is still not applying. Thanks

Comment: comments in CSS don't start with // but instead, the comment should be placed between /* ... */

Comment: besides, try to put more content and see the results... your problem usually happens when the body hasn't enough content...